# Myelinated vs Un-myelinated

Tags: neuroscience

If an axon is completely myelinated (doesn't even have Nodes of Ranvier), is it faster than an un-myelinated axon when conducting action potentials?

Comment: What do you think would happen in an axon without nodes of Ranvier?

Comment: The action potential would die out without any further stimulus, right?

Comment: Yes. So..what's the conduction velocity of something that doesn't conduct further?

Comment: Would the velocity be 0? And would that mean that the un-myelinated axon is faster?

Comment: Does it matter how fast a train is if it never gets to the destination? I wouldn't say the velocity is zero, it's meaningless.

Comment: Ok, thank you for explaining